# Return Value from XML Response

Tags: python, python-3.x, bigbluebutton

I am using 'bigbluebutton_api_python' and it returns response like:

```
{'xml': XMLDictNode(xml_attrs=OrderedDict(), value=OrderedDict([('returncode', XMLCDATANode(xml_attrs=OrderedDict(), value='SUCCESS')), ('createDate', XMLCDATANode(xml_attrs=OrderedDict(), value='Mon May 31 22:57:54 CEST 2021'))}
```

I need just to print createDate value like:

```
Mon May 31 22:57:54 CEST 2021
```

I tried:

```
playback_link = (full_responsee.split("'createDate'")[1].split("'))")[0])
```

but returns error.

How i can achieve that?

Comment: what is inside the full_respone? Show me the **Exact** data inside it

Comment: I use full_responsee = (b.get_meeting_info(meetingID)) to get meeting info but it returns this xml respone, i need to return value of createDate

Comment: It returns xml response because [BigBlueButton returns xml](https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#getmeetinginfo). The [Python API](https://github.com/101t/bigbluebutton-api-python) you use to get data uses the [jxmlease package](https://jxmlease.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to process the response. If it returns an XMLDictNode object, you can try to get the data using its methods. Or send requests to the BigBlueButton API endpoint and parse the xml yourself. Something similar to the code of [these projects](https://pypi.org/project/bigbluebutton).

Comment: What error did you get? `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'`?